# 8 bit Full Adder Simulation Program in Java

Tags: java

I have written the following code for 8 bit full adder.While debugging,the control from calling statement in main is going to `'eightbitfullAdderFunction'` but it is not evaluating anything in the function. 
I am getting 00000000 output for addition.Please help me with the code,I have tried making many changes in the logic but of no use.

```
public class CAModifiedBoothsMultiplier {

public byte[] twosComplement(byte x)
{
    byte y= (byte) (~x+1);

    byte mask=1;
    mask = (byte) (mask << 7);
    byte num[] = new byte[10];
    byte i=0;

    for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
    {
        if((y & mask)==0)
           num[i]=0;
        else
           num[i]=1;

        y=(byte) (y<<1);

    }

    return num;

}

public byte[] saveByte(byte number)
{
   byte mask=1;
    mask = (byte) (mask << 7);
    byte num[] = new byte[10];
    byte i=0;

    for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
    {
        if((number & mask)==0)
           num[i]=0;
        else
           num[i]=1;

        number=(byte) (number<<1);
    }
    return num;    
}

public byte[] eightbitFullAdder(byte a,byte b,byte cin)
{
    byte sum=0,temp1=0,cout=0;
    byte sumno[] = new byte[10];
    byte couttemp[]=new byte[10];

    couttemp[8]=cin;
    byte ain[]=saveByte(a);
    byte bin[]=saveByte(b);

    for(int i=8;i<=1;i--)
    {
        temp1= (byte) (ain[i] ^ bin[i]);

        sum = (byte) (temp1^couttemp[i]);
        sum=(byte) (sum<<7);
        sumno[i]=sum;

        cout=(byte) ((ain[i] & bin[i]) | (temp1 & couttemp[i]));

        if(i!=1)
          couttemp[--i]=cout;
    }



    return sumno;
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    CAModifiedBoothsMultiplier mbm = new CAModifiedBoothsMultiplier();
    byte x=5;
    byte complementedno[];
    complementedno = mbm.twosComplement(x);

    for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
        System.out.print(complementedno[i]);

    System.out.println("\n");

    byte a=2,b=3,cin=0;
    byte fulladder[] = mbm.eightbitFullAdder(a,b,cin);

    for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
        System.out.print(fulladder[i]);

 }

}
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?  This was probably a good opportunity to get familiar with how to use the debugger.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8.0 and I tried debugging it....it was not entering the loop....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your method "eightbitFullAdder" this line:

```
for(int i=8;i<=1;i--)
```

must be

```
for(int i=8;i>=1;i--)
```

otherwise, the for-loop is never entered

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that this for loop is checking that int i is less than rather than greater than or equal to 1 while counting down?
"for(int i=8;i<=1;i--)..."
Done the same thing more often than I care to remember, don't worry.

Comment: Edit: Ninja'd by a faster typer. Dirk's answer is more legible too. Would upvote but not enough rep, sorry Dirk.

Comment: Actually,it is meant to be "for(int i=8;i>0;i++)"....Code is working fine now...thanks :)